# Trying to start nginx, but port in use. Installed it via passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

I'm working on setting up a VPS with a Rails 3.1 application using nginx+passenger, and capistrano to boot strap it. At first, I installed nginx using a binary, forgetting that passenger installs it as well. When passenger asked me, I created a directory ~/opt/nginx for it to install into. Now, when I run the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
lsof -i:80
```

The server seems to stop, and nothing reports back at port 80. However, I then try to run

```
sudo ~/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

And it says:

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Any ideas what's going on? Note that I installed nginx this way because I am using a user rvm install, and therefore using `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module` would specify the wrong version of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run lsof with sudo?

Does this return anything listening on port 80?

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN*
```

When you connect to port 80 do you get any message?